# Command line sign Xcode project with embedded Framework

Tags: ios, xcode

We have a project that has a Framework project in it. It builds and be signed just fine from Xcode (10) but fails when done via the command line. The framework is set to automatically sign and "None Required" for the provisioning profile. The main project has it being embedded and "Code Sign on Copy" checked.

`Error Domain=IDEDistributionPipelineErrorDomain Code=0 "Code signing "FooLibrary.framework" failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Code signing "FooLibrary.framework" failed., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=View distribution logs for more information.}`

Not much useful info in the logs. Any tips appreciated. Thx.

EDIT: What's also interesting is when this fails it leaves the system in an inconsistent state and it won't let me sign other apps until I reboot.